# Json server update

Tags: angularjs, json, http

I'm using [json-server](https://github.com/typicode/json-server) and I'm able to do post and get. But I'am not able to do a update.

In my database, I have this data:

```
{
  "userRecipes": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "desc": "dog",
      "flag" : true
    }
  ]
}
```

I wish to update the flag, for doing this I have used this code but it doesn't work:

```
loginDataSend.flag = true;     
$http
       (
          {
              method: 'update',
 url: 'http://localhost:3000/userRecipes/' + id,
   data: loginDataSend,
   dataType: "json"
    }
   ).error(funcion()
                 {
                 // Error code here
                 alert("error");
                 })
                 .success(function ()
                 {
                 alert("ok");    
                 });
```

I thank you for your help.

Comment: try to use keyword "put" instead of 'update'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`update` is not a valid HTTP method.

You seem to be striving for REST-based API. The REST paradigm is built upon the HTTP protocol and thus there is a inherent mapping between the HTTP Methods you use and the CRUD operations over the entities you want to achieve.

In HTTP you have the following methods available:

- `POST`- generally used for creation under the REST paradigm.
- `PUT` - used for updates under the REST paradigm.
- `DELETE` - used for deletion.
- `GET` - generally used for reading.

In your case you should use `PUT` because you want to make an update.

Answer (score 0):

You can use PUT method instead 'updade' method, then it automatically converts that into post method and your data will be updated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
const res = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/userRecipes/' + id, {
    method: 'PATCH',
    headers: {
       'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({ dataToUpdate}),
})
```